# i want to display an item in between a for each loop

Tags: php

i had this code

```
<ul class="links"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
        <?php if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):?>
            <?php echo $_link->toHtml() ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

now i know that i had four links but i want to insert "wishlist" after 1st so how could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

With an extra variable count

```
$count=0;
<?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
     <?php
       $count++;
        if ($count == 2)
        {
         ?>
         //wishlist link here
        <?php
        } 
       //your existing code in foreach
      ?>    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Instead of an additional variable you could also use `foreach($_links as $count => $_link)` if the array keys are numeric.

Comment: @acme: Yes, we can do but we are not clear about type of array indexes and also the index number if array contain 11,12,13,14 indexes it will not work